# Java SQLite execSQL Syntax Error

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I have the following execSQL in my android project that is throwing a syntax error and causing my app to crash. I can't figure out why.

```
private static final String TABLE_QUESTIONS = "question";
private static final String KEY_ID_Q = "id";
private static final String KEY_QUESTION_Q = "question";
private static final String KEY_ANSWER1_Q = "answer1";
private static final String KEY_ANSWER2_Q = "answer2";
private static final String KEY_ANSWER3_Q = "answer3";
private static final String KEY_ANSWER4_Q = "answer4";
private static final String KEY_TYPE_Q = "type_Q";
[... ]


    String CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_QUESTIONS + "("
            + KEY_ID_Q + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_QUESTION_Q + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_ANSWER1_Q + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_ANSWER2_Q + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_ANSWER3_Q + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_ANSWER4_Q + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_TYPE_Q + "INTEGER" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE);
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUESTIONS +" (" + KEY_QUESTION_Q + ", " + KEY_ANSWER1_Q + ", " + KEY_ANSWER2_Q+ ", " + KEY_ANSWER3_Q + ", " + KEY_ANSWER4_Q + ", " + KEY_TYPE_Q + ") VALUES (" + QUESTION[a] + ", "+(a*4+1)+", "+(a*4+2)+", "+(a*4+3)+", "+(a*4+4)+", "+q_type+");");
```

LogCat:

```
    09-28 21:27:26.629: E/Database(1070): Failure 1 (table question has no column named type_Q) on 0x2c3868 when preparing 'INSERT INTO question (question, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, type_Q) VALUES ('AnyString', 1, 2, 3, 4, 1);'.
```

I hope some of you guys can figure it out :)

Answer (score 2):

It's as simple as that you forgot a space;

```
+ KEY_TYPE_Q + "INTEGER" + ")";
```

should be

```
+ KEY_TYPE_Q + " INTEGER" + ")";
```

...otherwise you'll try to create a field called `type_QINTEGER` with no type.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer but it seems to be it´s not the mistake I am looking for. This doesn´t solve the Problem. Also the LogCat Log already told about a missing column named type_Q and not type_QINTEGER. 
LogCat:

        `09-29 11:16:39.017: E/Database(371): Failure 1 (table question has no column named type_Q) on 0x2c31c8 when preparing 'INSERT INTO question (question, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, type_Q) VALUES ('AnyString', 1, 2, 3, 4, 1);'.`

Comment: @ChrisM If the space does not help, you probably already created the table without the type_Q field, and the create table will just fail silently dues to the table already existing.

Comment: I was checking the code again but can´t find a further initialization of the table 'question'. I know it´s not clear to see in my code example but the creat table call is written into the onCreate() function. So this should only be called once right?

Comment: Well, OnCreate will run each time you start the app, and the next time it starts the table already exists and won't be re-created. You may want to look into [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html).